# Как запустить сервер node.js на vps?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vps

Запустил командой node server.js.
server.js находиться в папке /home/server. VPS на Ubuntu.
Сервер запустился но соединение не открывает по ip:8080

```
const http = require('http')

const hostname = '85.208.208.138'
const port = 8080

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.end('Hello world')
})

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
})
```

Comment: Так вы же сервер поднимаете на 8000 порту, почему он должен отвечать на порту 8080?

Comment: Сделал опечатку в примере кода, но там стоит 8080

Comment: Попробовал ещё запустить, вывело сообщение - Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 85.208.208.138:8080

Comment: в  firewall порт добавили ?

Comment: @РоманЮсупов ну значит ищите кто ещё занимает порт 8080

Comment: Попробуйте запустить на каком нибудь не стандартном порту, ну допустим 3456

Comment: Теперь всё работает, добавил порт в настройках файрвола - ufw allow 8080